# Debugging memory leaks with libMallocDebug

Tags: c++, debugging, macos, memory-leaks, malloc

I want to use the MallocDebug app to find some memory leaks in my app. I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.2. Whenever I try and following the instructions listed in [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/ManagingMemory.pdf), I get the following error:

```
dyld: could not load inserted library: /usr/lib/libMallocDebug.A.dylib

Trace/BPT trap
```

I have verified that the .dylib file exists, and I get the same error no matter which app I try and run (it's not limited to my application). [Several others](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2332597&tstart=0) have [reported this problem](http://compgroups.net/comp.sys.mac.programmer.help/libMallocDebug-question) as well, but so far no one has found a solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

libMallocDebug is not available for 64-bit executables.

```
% lipo -info /usr/lib/libMallocDebug.A.dylib    
Architectures in the fat file: /usr/lib/libMallocDebug.A.dylib are: i386 ppc7400
```

It does appear to work with 32-bit executables in 10.6, though, for example:

```
% lipo -thin i386 /bin/ls -out foo
% DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/libMallocDebug.A.dylib ./foo        
libMallocDebug[foo-9141]: initializing libMallocDebug on thread 903
[...]
```

I'm not sure whether this is an oversight or it was never ported to the 64-bit runtime.  You might try filing a bug.

**Update:** Seems there are just more debugging features in the regular malloc now.  [This](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/01/10/using-malloc-to-debug-memory-misuse-in-cocoa/) discussion is pretty good.

Comment: I have just now filed a bug - Are there any alternative tools I can use, since this one seems to be unavailable?

Comment: You can't just compile your app as 32-bit?  There is the `leaks` command-line tool.  Valgrind kinda works with Snow Leopard but may not work to your satisfaction (you'll need to build it yourself; see the discussion at https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205241).

Comment: not really. According to apple, the MallocDebug method is being deprecated, in favour of the Instruments application, although I personally can't seem to get that particular app to do anything sensible.